# Showing two fields of attribute table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I need to show two fields of an attribute table. I can currently display the "POINT" field.
I also want to show the "ID" field.
In the following way, if ID = 2 and POINT = 341. It should show like this 2 (341). As shown in the picture.

```
# Adding Labels to Nodes
```

for layer in
QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
        text_format = QgsTextFormat()

```
text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 8))
text_format.setSize(8)
text_format.setColor(QColor('Black'))


buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
buffer_settings.setSize(0.10)
buffer_settings.setColor(QColor('black'))

text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

fieldName1="PUNTO"
fieldName2="ID"
layer_settings.fieldName = "PUNTO" ***********************************
layer_settings.placement = 4

layer_settings.enabled = True

layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
layer5.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer5.setLabeling(layer_settings)
layer5.triggerRepaint()[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Please see the other question I linked above. I have added an answer there for QGIS 3. Essentially you just have to create an expression concatenating your "ID" & "PUNTO" fields and the parenthesis characters. Use this expression: `"""concat("ID",'(',"PUNTO",')')"""`  instead of the single field name, then set isExpression to True: `layer_settings.isExpression = True`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it worked perfect